# symfony 2 lesscss paths

Tags: symfony, less

I'm using assetic with less filter and storing main less file in app/Resources/...
I'd like to import into that file other less stylesheets from inside bundles.
Everything works fine but the paths are driving me nuts.

My base.less looks more or less like this:

```
@import 'normalize.less';
@import 'mixins.less';
@import 'header.less';
@import 'footer.less';

@import "../../../../../../src/Acme/FooBundle/Resources/public/less/example.less";
```

Is there a way to pass 'paths' option to less compiler in symfony2?

EDIT: I've found a issue for my problem on assetic's repo on github:
https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/pull/218

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to store the path in a variable like they say in the less documentation?

```
@base-url: "http://assets.fnord.com";
background-image: url("@{base-url}/images/bg.png");
```

This is not exactly what you want but this way you define it only once.